# force empty cells to end of sorted column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to sort a sheet by a column that has strings in it.  I'm populating the sheet by putting a query based on an import range in the first cell.  It seemed best if I did the sort as part of the query, order by Col6.  This places all the empty rows at the top unless I sort descending, which I do not want to do.  I found the opposite of what I want to do in the question titled "sort-empty-cells-to-top"

The answer there gets the values of the sheet's data range and works with the values array, then puts it back into the range. How would I change the compare function to force empty cells to the bottom in an ascending sort?

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want. You may have to build a helper column with somrthing in each row you want to return (like my Col7 (column G)).

```
=query(query(Sheet1!A1:G,"select * order by F "),"Select * where Col7 <>''")
```

Comment: I'll test in the morning -- I can use my sort column to check for nulls.

Comment: Here is a share of the spreadsheet I tested with. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFN6I9JnpaxkhkAALOSJHLKnqYWDA02NuRgkfxBWnpg/edit?usp=sharing